# Is there a simple way to change a column of yes/no to 1/0 in a Pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I read a csv file into a pandas dataframe, and would like to convert the columns with binary answers from strings of yes/no to integers of 1/0. Below, I show one of such columns ("sampleDF" is the pandas dataframe).

```
In [13]: sampleDF.housing[0:10]
Out[13]:
0     no
1     no
2    yes
3     no
4     no
5     no
6     no
7     no
8    yes
9    yes
Name: housing, dtype: object
```

Help is much appreciated!

Comment: `sampleDF.housing.replace(('yes', 'no'), (1, 0), inplace=True)`

Comment: **Note:** Python has bools, and so does NumPy. Use them, not `0`/`1`, or `'0'`/`'1'`.

Answer (score 128):

***method 1***

```
sample.housing.eq('yes').mul(1)
```

***method 2***

```
pd.Series(np.where(sample.housing.values == 'yes', 1, 0),
          sample.index)
```

***method 3***

```
sample.housing.map(dict(yes=1, no=0))
```

***method 4***

```
pd.Series(map(lambda x: dict(yes=1, no=0)[x],
              sample.housing.values.tolist()), sample.index)
```

***method 5***

```
pd.Series(np.searchsorted(['no', 'yes'], sample.housing.values), sample.index)
```

---

All yield

```
0    0
1    0
2    1
3    0
4    0
5    0
6    0
7    0
8    1
9    1
```

---

***timing***
given sample

[image]

***timing***
long sample
`sample = pd.DataFrame(dict(housing=np.random.choice(('yes', 'no'), size=100000)))`

[image]

Comment: This is a great in depth answer. I wouldn't have even thought of some of these.

Comment: Can you do an entire dataframe full of yes and nos?  I'm looking at this congressional vote dataset:  http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Congressional+Voting+Records

Answer (score 41):

Try this:

```
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].map({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

Answer (score 17):

```
# produces True/False
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'] == 'yes'
```

The above returns True/False values which are essentially 1/0, respectively. Booleans support sum functions, etc. If you really need it to be 1/0 values, you can use the following.

```
housing_map = {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].map(housing_map)
```

Answer (score 8):

```
%timeit
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].apply(lambda x: 0 if x=='no' else 1)
```

1.84 ms ± 56.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000 loops each)

> > > Replaces 'yes' with 1, 'no' with 0 for the df column specified.

Answer (score 5):

Use sklearn's LabelEncoder

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

lb = LabelEncoder() 
sampleDF['housing'] = lb.fit_transform(sampleDF['housing'])
```

[Source](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.LabelEncoder.html)

Answer (score 4):

yes there is you can change yes/no values of your column to 1/0 by using following code snippet

```
sampleDF = sampleDF.replace(to_replace = ['yes','no'],value = ['1','0'])
sampleDF
```

by using first line you can replace the values with 1/0 
by using second line you can see the changes by printing it

Answer (score 3):

Generic way:

```
import pandas as pd
string_data = string_data.astype('category')
numbers_data = string_data.cat.codes
```

reference:
https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.astype.html

Answer (score 3):

For a dataset names data and a column named `Paid`;

```
data = data.replace({'Paid': {'yes': 1, 'no': 0}})
```

all the `yes` will change to `1` and all the `no` will be replaced by `0`

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a series from Boolean to integer explicitly:

```
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].eq('yes').astype(int)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easy way to do that use pandas as below:

```
housing = pd.get_dummies(sampleDF['housing'],drop_first=True)
```

after that drop this filed from main df

```
sampleDF.drop('housing',axis=1,inplace=True)
```

now merge new one in you df

```
sampleDF= pd.concat([sampleDF,housing ],axis=1)
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple and intuitive way to convert the whole dataframe to 0's and 1's might be:

```
sampleDF = sampleDF.replace(to_replace = "yes", value = 1)
sampleDF = sampleDF.replace(to_replace = "no", value = 0)
```

Comment: You can do this in a single line as well :                                                                            `sampleDF = sampleDF.replace( to_replace = {"no" : 0, "yes" : 1})`

Answer (score 1):

```
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].map(lambda x: 1 if x == 'yes' else 0)
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].astype(int)
```

This will work.

Answer (score 1):

Try this, it will work.

```
sampleDF.housing.replace(['no', 'yes'], [0,1], inplace = True)
```

Answer (score 1):

use pandas.Series.map

`sampleDF.map({'yes':1,'no':0})`

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
sampleDF['housing'] = sampleDF['housing'].str.lower().replace({'yes': 1, 'no': 0})
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the preprocesssing function from sklearn. First you create an encoder.

```
e = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
```

Then for each attribute or characteristic in the data use the label encoder to transform it into an integer value

```
size = le.fit_transform(list(data["size"]))
color = le.fit_transform(list(data["color"]))
```

It's converting a list of all the "size" or "color" attributes, and converting that into a list of their corresponding integer values. To put all of this into one list, use the zip function.

It is not going to be in the same format as the csv file; it will be a giant list of everything.

```
data = list(zip(buying, size))
```

Hopefully I explained that somewhat clearly.

Comment: Isn't this a bit risky, like many uses of `string.replace()`, since it will replace the values **everywhere**?

Comment: Yeah, I found a better solution so I put that. I don't think I explained it very well though.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try :

```
sampleDF["housing"] = (sampleDF["housing"]=="Yes")*1
```

Answer (score 0):

This is just a bool to int.

Try this.

`sampleDF.housing = (sampleDF.housing == 'yes').astype(int)`

Answer (score 0):

comprehension array

```
sampleDF['housing'] = [int(v == 'yes') for v in sampleDF['housing']]
```