# How to replace data in csv file based on criteria?

Tags: python, pandas, if-statement, jupyter

I want to replace all data in `WinorLoss` column from W/L to 1/0 (1 if W and 0 if L)..

`WinorLoss` is a column in my csv file which is populated with W's or L's for corresponding games

I have tried the following:

```
if df.WinorLoss == "W":
 df.WinorLoss == "1"
else:
 df.WinorLoss == "0"
```

Got the following error:
`ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().`

I am new to python so am not 100% how to go about to do this.. any help would be appreciated?

Comment: `df['WinorLoss'].map({'W': 1, 'L': 0})` or with `numpy.where`: `np.where(df['WinorLoss'] == 'W', 1, 0)`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to change a column of yes/no to 1/0 in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901770/is-there-a-simple-way-to-change-a-column-of-yes-no-to-1-0-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
df.WinorLoss.map(lambda x: "1" if x == "W" else "0")
```