# how to optimize these pandas apply functions?

Tags: pandas, lambda, apply

```
train["gender"] = train.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["gender"] == "F" else 0, axis=1) 
train["car"] = train.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["car"] == "Y" else 0, axis=1) 
train["reality"] = train.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["reality"] == "Y" else 0, axis=1)
```

these 3 codes require many time even it is simple change.
I guess, accessing each row 3 times makes inefficeny.
So, if I can make 1 access to row and apply function change 3 data, it can be faster 2~3 times than now.

like.....

```
# it is my imaginary code. not works
train[["gender","car", "reality"]] =  train.apply(lambda x: 1 if x["gender"] == "F" else 0, axis=1,
                                                  lambda y: 1 if y["car"] == "Y" else 0, axis=1,
                                                  lambda z: 1 if z["reality"] == "Y" else 0, axis=1)
```

How can optimize these codes?

===========================
test result for tdy

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try 3x [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which is [generally the fastest option](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40902719/13138364):

```py
train['gender'] = np.where(train.gender == 'F', 1, 0)
train['car'] = np.where(train.car == 'Y', 1, 0)
train['reality'] = np.where(train.reality == 'Y', 1, 0)
```

Or 2x [**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) which is slightly slower:

```py
train['gender'] = np.where(train.gender == 'F', 1, 0)
train[['car', 'reality']] = np.where(train[['car', 'reality']] == 'Y', 1, 0)
```

Timings with 10 million rows:

| method | `%timeit` |
| --- | --- |
| 3x `np.where()` | 152 ms ± 8.86 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) |
| 2x `np.where()` | 198 ms ± 39.3 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) |
| 3x `apply()` | 8.91 s ± 495 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each) |

Comment: oh, I will try this. But I think this solution also has same problem. Access each row 3 times

Comment: @LaserCho I edited the answer to combine `car` and `reality`. I'm not aware of a way to include all 3 at once since `gender` has a different condition.

Comment: very interesting. your original answer "np.where 3 times" is fastest. and second is current answer. my original 3 time apply is slowest. fastest way is faster than second almost 16 times. and second-current answer is faster than my code 35 times.

Comment: @LaserCho I added another option to do it all in one shot, but I'm not sure if it's actually faster.

Comment: Scratch that, some bugs in it I haven't figured out.