# Pandas vectorization: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous

Tags: python, pandas

I'm currently trying to apply the concept of vectorization using Pandas. I've been successfully able to use crude looping, but on the same code, when I try to vectorize and pass the entire Series to a function I get

```
ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().
```

My function is rather simple:

```py
def price_function(x):
    if x >= 50:
        return "High"
    else:
        return "low"
```

And I'm calling it with the `price` Series of a Dataframe with the following:

```
listing_price = price_function(listings_dataframe_big['price'])
```

And the error is being triggered by the following line:

```
if x >= 50:
```

Any idea on why is this happening and how to fix this?

Comment: Since a series has multiple values, then evaluating s > 50 is ambiguous, because part of the series could be True and other parts False.  Do you want to check to see if all values are great than 50 or if a single value is greater than 50.  use `all` or `any`.

Comment: You do `np.where(listings_dataframe_big['price'] >=50, 'high', 'low')`. It is super fast

Comment: Note that `apply` and `map` are not vectorizations. `np.where` is vectorized.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that [**`apply()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.apply.html) and [**`map()`**](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) are *not* vectorizations, just loops in disguise.

[**`np.where()`**](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) is vectorized and thus [generally the fastest method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40902719/13138364):

```py
listing_price = np.where(listings_dataframe_big['price'] >= 50, 'High', 'Low')
```

But as Scott mentioned, the original issue is that when `x` is a series, `x >= 50` is ambiguous because pandas doesn't know if you want [`(x >= 50).any()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.any.html) or [`(x >= 50).all()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.all.html).

Answer (score 0):

The way to apply a function to all values of a series would be to use `map`.

```py
listing_price = listings_dataframe_big['price'].map(price_function)
```

But as already mentioned, `np.were` is easier and most likely faster.