# Format the values of a dataframe column from integer to string

Tags: python, pandas

Currently I have a dataframe with columns but for this purpose, I'll just list the columns of importance. Basically I have a dataframe like this:

```
id  type
1   1
2   1
3   2
4   2
5   1
```

But I want to format the integers such that

```
1 = 'One'
2 = 'Two'
```

But I don't want to change the int to a string like using pd.replace, but format it instead.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for? [`df.to_string`, `df.to_html`, or `df.style.format`](/a/36175424/4518341)

Comment: Can you solve this with a dictionary that you load or is that too much like `replace()`? I can't imagine there is a built in formatter to convert an integer to an english string representation like this... but it is python, so who knows. Also, I'm assuming possible entries aren't limited to `1` and `2`, right?

Comment: `df["type"].map({1: "One", 2: "Two"})`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a simple way to change a column of yes/no to 1/0 in a Pandas dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40901770/is-there-a-simple-way-to-change-a-column-of-yes-no-to-1-0-in-a-pandas-dataframe)

Comment: `"But I don't want to change the int to a string"` so I don't think they want to `map` it either. The current question's wording is confusing.

Comment: Basically, I want the output to be this:

id  type
1   One
2   One
3   Two
4   Two
5   One

But I want the type column to stay an int.

Edit: I don't know how to make my output in stack to be easy to read, thanks to whoever made it readable.

Comment: Okay gold_cy, I'll try that

Comment: Well the map function pretty much does the same thing as the replace function.
It turns the column that was an int to a Object which is basically a string.
What I want is for it to stay an 'int64' but just format those values for output.

Answer (score 0):

you can actually use replace function on pandas.
For example,

```
df['type'].replace(1, 'one')
```

then, you can try replace all the keyword such as for two, three, and so on.